# call Read Reports API from MS Graph API in Microsoft Teams but using this Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm trying to call Read Reports API from MS Graph API in Microsoft Teams but using this API :

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')?$format=application/json`

but it gives me the following error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): 
{
   "error": {
      "code":"S2SUnauthorized",
      "message":"Invalid permission."
   }
}
```

I'm using MSAL authentication and Graph client, I did everything exactly the same in the tutorial of Microsoft Graph and I provided the required permission, Registered the App, added everything correctly in Azure and Granted permission by admin, changed them to Application from delegate it works for all other APIs but this API isn't working.

Comment: Would you kindly share a requestID and date so we can look into this further ? Are you using  Graph explorer to make this request?

Comment: Could you please share the documentation what exactly your following.

Comment: @Ala Mashaqi - If you are  still facing the issue please share the response header. Are you trying it in graph explorer or postman?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't found any documentation related to call Read Reports API. It could be helpful if you have shared the tutorial which you are following. Please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) for call record API